# Method for finding a maximum of a convex function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, maximum-principle

I have the following maximization problem:

\begin{align}
\max_{v_i} \quad & \left(1-\frac{c}{2}\right) \sum_{i=1}^n v_i -\frac{ \left(  k -\delta    \right)}{\sum^k_{i=1}\frac{1}{v_i}} \label{The OP} \\
\textrm{s.t.}  \quad & 1\leq v_i\leq n-1  \quad &\forall i \in [1,n], \label{integers}\\
\textrm{    }  \quad & \sum_{i=1}^y v_i \leq y(y-1) + \sum_{i=y+1}^n \min (v_i,y)  \quad &\forall y \in [1,n], \label{EG conditions O}\\
\textrm{    } \quad & \frac{k-\delta-1}{\sum_{ j \in K \setminus \{i\}} \frac{1}{v_j}} -  v_i \leq  0 \quad &\forall  i \in [1,k], \textrm{ } \textrm{                (*)} \\
\textrm{    }  \quad & -  \frac{ \left(  k -\delta    \right)}{\sum^k_{i=1}\frac{1}{v_i}} + v_j \leq 0 \quad &\forall  j \in (k,n], \label{not attacked nodes} 
\end{align}

Observe that the objective function is convex. Originally, it was an integer maximization problem related to optimal network formation.

Observe also that constraint $(*)$ is concave. Thus this is a problem of convex function maximization on a non-convex set.

Therefore, additionally, I consider a Convex Hull of the set instead of the set itself. A tight convex hull can be achieved by replacing condition $(*)$ with a set of linear constraints, which spans through the extreme points of the concave function. After this, I applied Bauer maximum principle and started to search for extremes. I managed to show analytically that only three potential integer sequences $\vec{v}$ are at the extremes of a convex hull.

Then I verified numerically and realized that those three sequences happen to coincide with real maximizers (At least for $n<11$). I performed numerical verification by iterating the real degree sequences of networks (taken from the Wolfram database) for $n$ up to $11$, revealing the sequences that yield the maximum for a given $c$.

I am not very familiar with optimization. So the only question I have is whether it is a sound approach to this particular maximization problem. I could not find much literature about the Bauer maximum principle used for problems like that.

Comment: It sounds like you want to impose additional integer  constraints on the original problem. Then, it sounds like you are hoping that there is at least one optimal solution to the integer-constrained problem that also is an extreme point of the convex hull of your constraint set. It is not clear why that should be true. It is not true in general, consider maximizing $x$ subject to $x\leq 1.5$.  The only extreme point of the constraint set is $1.5$, which is not an integer, whereas the solution to the integer-constrained problem is $x=1$.

Comment: Your first constraint has no $y$ so it is not clear what "$\forall y \in [1,n]$" is doing. I assume $[1,n]=\{1, ..., n\}$.

Comment: @Michael, thank you for your response. Yes $y$ is just iterating the condition for values $1$ to $n$.  What I have tried to achieve is: (1) relax an original integer maximisation problem in two ways: (1.1) integer-relaxation and (1.2) convex relaxation (restating constraints $(*)$ in the linear form). Then find all possible extreme points of the relaxed set. It happens that three of them are always integer. I think it should imply that (given that they pass all the constraints of the original integer problem) that they are potential maximisers for the original problem too.

Comment: Again your first constraint does not make sense. Perhaps it should be $i \in \{1, ..., n\}$. Any vectors that satisfy the constraints of the original problem are indeed "potential" maximizers of the original problem.

Comment: @Michael, yes, you are right. I fixed it in the body now. I am sorry for that.

Comment: Does this problem belong to NP-hard problems?

Comment: I don't know, it would take some time to think about. It is interesting to find all integer extreme points of the convex hull as you mention. I do not know if that includes all possible integer solutions to the original problem.

Comment: @Michael, I have performed this exercise already. I have relaxed integrality constraints and Erdos-Gallai constraints. I have also replaced each non-convex constraint with k-2 linear `hyperplane' constraints. The analysis of the convex hull provides exactly three extreme points that are integer and graphic: star, complete and one more (looks like several stars glued together, for instance, 4-4-2-2-2).

Comment: Iterative numerical verification reveals that those three-degree sequences are indeed real global maximisers for different values of $c$: complete for low $c$, star for high $c$ and the third option for intermediate values of $c$. However, I performed numerical verification only for reasonably small graphs with n<20. Note, however, that my network dataset is not quite complete for n>9.

Comment: I can share these results here if you are interested.

Comment: I may glance at it but perhaps will not have time to look at it thoroughly. It seems involved.